# What would be the time complexity of finding Power set of an array?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, set, time-complexity, recurrence

The task is to find the Power Set of an array which is to find set of all subsets of an array for example for [1,2] it will be [[],[1],[2],[1,2]]. For an n length array, the power set is 2^n long. It is evident when I try to do it using recursion and 2 calls like below

```
class Solution:
    
    def helperSubsets(self,output_li, nums, klist):
        if len(nums)==0:
            output_li.append(klist)
            return
        self.helperSubsets(output_li,nums[1:],klist+[nums[0]])
        self.helperSubsets(output_li,nums[1:],klist)
    
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        output_li = []
        self.helperSubsets(output_li,nums,[])
        return output_li
```

Recurrence Relation is : T(n) = 2T(n-1) + O(1)

But when trying to do it using for loop in recursive call, how do I prove or find the time complexity of the recursion, what would be the Recurrence relation also if you know. I am not able to figure it out. Reference of doing it with for loop and recursion:

```
class Solution:
    
    def helperSubsets(self,output_li, nums, klist):
        output_li.append(klist)
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            self.helperSubsets(output_li,nums[i+1:],klist+[nums[i]])
    
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        output_li = []
        self.helperSubsets(output_li,nums,[])
        return output_li
```

In the first example, the element is either being picked or not, so the recursive calls are being divided twice at each element so complexity is 2^n. But for the second code which is doing the same thing, how do I find the complexity? (apart from knowing it's doing the same thing as the first so it'll be similar). Can you also give me the recurrence relation for it if you know?

Comment: Easy way to prove the time complexity of such an algorithm, not matte whether it's recursive or iterative: (1) Prove that your algorithm takes one time-step per element in the answer; (2) You already know that the length of the answer is `n 2^n`; (3) This proves that the time complexity of your algorithm is `n 2^n`.

Comment: Note it's `n 2^n` and not just `2^n`, because the answer is a list of `2^n` lists, and each of these lists is of length `n` in average.

Comment: @Stef "of length n in average" no it is much smaller.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Is it? For a set of size `n`, for any integer `k` such that 0 <= k <= n, the number of subsets of length `k` is equal to the number of subsets of size `n-k`. Thus by symmetry, the average length of a subset should be exactly `n/2`. Which is proportional to `n`. I dropped the `/2` factor in my previous comment.

Comment: @Stef You are right, this is a brain fart on my part

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Sorry, I have trouble following you. Here is me observing how the average length behaves as n grows: `from more_itertools import powerset; from statistics import mean; [mean(len(s) for s in powerset(range(n))) for n in range(20)]`. Results: `[0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5]`. You can compare with `[n / 2 for n in range(20)]` if you need to.